# Sorting of Google Charts in Sharepoint

Tags: google-chart

I have a Google Chart that is created from a SharePoint List.
The sorting of the chart results from which items appear first when going down from row to row:

```
function drawBarCharts(countChoices, name) {
        var rows = [];
        for (var property in countChoices) {
            if (countChoices.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                rows.push([property, countChoices[property]]);
            }
        }


        var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        datatable.addColumn('string', 'Type');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
        datatable.addRows(rows);
        var options = {
            title: String(name),
            is3D: 'true',
            hAxis:{direction: -1}
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById(String(name)));
        chart.draw(datatable, options);
```

How can I manually sort the data with a manual order, or by name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `DataView` and the `setRows` method to create a custom sort.
`setRows` takes an array of row indexes.

add the row indexes to the array in the order to be displayed,
then use the `DataView` to draw the chart.

see following code snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  datatable.addColumn('string', 'Type');
  datatable.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
  datatable.addRows([
    ['A', 2],
    ['B', 4],
    ['C', 6],
    ['S', 4],
    ['U', 2]
  ]);

  var dataview = new google.visualization.DataView(datatable);
  dataview.setRows([0, 2, 3, 4, 1]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Custom Sort',
    is3D: 'true',
    hAxis:{direction: -1}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataview, options);
});
```

Comment: hope this helps, here is a working fiddle --> [https://jsfiddle.net/zcp4rm9d/](https://jsfiddle.net/zcp4rm9d/)

Answer (score 0):

You can **only** sort by the columns that already added to the **Datatable** of the Google Chart `desc` or `asc` as the following

```
datatable.sort({column: 0, desc: true});
```

In this case, it will **sort** the datatable by `Type` column descending!

Comment: ok something was sorted, but not in the way i want it to be sorted. What are the options i have?

Comment: As I told you it depends on the columns in your data table, so if you need to add order as you need , add a new column called order and set the order value like 1,2,3, and sort with this new column in your datatable !!